# Is there a way to change format from text to Date given in an excel file for MailMerge purposes?

Tags: python, mailmerge

Hope you are keeping safe,

I'm trying to do a mailmerge that will capture the data from an excel file named 'source1' and create word templates using the template.doc file.

the output is fine, but the format needs to be fixed for some columns in the excel file such as dates. for some reasons dates are including hours

example the output in the template generated is 2020-12-12 00:00:00 while the required format must be 12 Dec 2020.

below is the code

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge

import openpyxl

import datetime

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('source1.xlsx')

sheet= wb['Sheet1']

max_col = sheet.max_row

sheet.delete_rows(sheet.min_row,1)

for i in range(1, max_col):

    template='template.docx'

    document1=MailMerge(template)

    document1.merge(

        first_name = str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value),

        last_name = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 2).value),

        salary = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).value),

        Date = str (sheet.cell(row = i, column =4 ).value),

        date1='{:%d-%b-%Y}'.format(Date),

      #  country = str ( sheet.cell(row = i, column = 5). value),

       # Title = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 6).value),

       # item = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 7).value),

      # price = '$'+str(sheet.cell(row = i, column=8).value),

      #  quantity = str(sheet.cell(row=i, column = 9).value),

       # total = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 10).value),

        )

    document1.write('Letter for ' +str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value)+'.docx')
```

I tried to use

```
    Date = str (sheet.cell(row = i, column =4 ).value),

    date1='{:%d-%b-%Y}'.format(Date),
```

but it gave me error 'Date is not defined' !

Comment: Can you please provide reproducable code? It will make it easier for people to simulate and answer you question. Pls avoid references to external files

Comment: thanks for that but this doesn't work because the date will not be visible as it does mail merge.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You are incorrectly attempting to convert the date format. For this, you will want to use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library, not string formatting.
2. `Date` is a named argument to `document1.merge()` so you can't access it within the function call. You can see from [the example usage](https://github.com/Bouke/docx-mailmerge#usage) of the library that `document.merge` takes `kwargs` that correspond to the merge fields, but you're trying to create regular variables *within* this function call.

To fix this, you should do the date conversion before the function call:

```
import datetime as dt

...

for i in range(1, max_col):

    # Convert the format here
    Date = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column =4 ).value) # Assuming format e.g. 2020-05-01
    date1 = dt.datetime.strptime(Date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

    template = 'template.docx'
    document1 = MailMerge(template)
    document1.merge(first_name = str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value),
                    last_name = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 2).value),
                    salary = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).value),
                    date1 = date1)

    document1.write('Letter for ' +str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value)+'.docx')
```